# C Compilation Make Error, It's Trying to Compile Comment Line

Tags: makefile

I'm not too familiar with C but this is pretty weird.  I'm running the `make` command on a makefile I made to compile my C modules on an HP-UX (nightmare!) machine.  Things are compiling correctly but towards the end I get this error:

`Make: Don't know how to make #----------------.  Stop.`

It looks like it's trying to `make` the start of a comment line I have in the makefile.  Here is the makefile (it's ugly, not something I wrote in the first place):

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#  Name : Makefile
#--------------------------------------------------------------

CCOPTS    = -c +DD64 -Ae -I/path/to/include
DEFINES   = -DUNIX
INCLUDE  = /path/to/include
BIN       = /path/to/bin


FIRSTOBJS = asvc.o getname.o err.o 
SECONDOBJS  = CCARD.o getname.o err.o
THIRDOBJS  = CREQ.o getname.o err.o
FOURTHOBJS = CPORG.o implin.o getname.o cchcomm.o err.o
FIFTHOBJS = UNFOR.o getname.o err.o

DBINCDIR = /path/to/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-hpux11.11-hppa2.0-64bit/include
LIBS      = -lmysqlclient
DBLIB    = +DD64 -L/path/to/lib

#---------------- All Executables -------------------
default : $(BIN)/asvc \
    $(BIN)/UNFOR \
    $(BIN)/ontop \
    $(BIN)/CCARD \
    $(BIN)/CREQ \
    $(BIN)/xltscri \

#---------------- Common object Modules -------------                   
asvc.o : asvc.c $(INCLUDE)/err.h $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) asvc.c

err.o : err.c $(INCLUDE)/err.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) -g err.c -I$(DBINCDIR)

UNFOR.o : UNFOR.c $(INCLUDE)/err.h $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) UNFOR.c

xltscri.o : xltscri.c $(INCLUDE)/ontop.h $(INCLUDE)/err.h \
     $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) xltscri.c

ontop.o : ontop.c $(INCLUDE)/ontop.h $(INCLUDE)/err.h \
    $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) ontop.c

getname.o : getname.c  $(INCLUDE)/ontop.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR)  getname.c

CCARD.o : CCARD.c  $(INCLUDE)/err.h $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) CCARD.c

implin.o : implin.c $(INCLUDE)/err.h $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) implin.c -I$(DBINCDIR)

CREQ.o : CREQ.c  $(INCLUDE)/err.h $(INCLUDE)/xcerr.h
    cc $(CCOPTS) $(DEFINES) -I$(DBINCDIR) CREQ.c

#------------ Make asvc (Get SubService ) ---------                   
$(BIN)/asvc: $(FIRSTOBJS)
    cc -o $@         \
    $(FIRSTOBJS)  \
    $(DBLIB)     \
    $(LIBS)

#------------ Make CCARD (Update Completed TimeStamp ) ---------   
$(BIN)/CCARD: $(SECONDOBJS)
    cc -o $@      \
    $(SECONDOBJS)  \
    $(DBLIB)     \
    $(LIBS)

#------------ Make UNFOR ( Match Partitioning Abend Checker ) ---------    
$(BIN)/UNFOR: $(FIFTHOBJS)
    cc -o $@         \
    $(FIFTHOBJS)  \
    $(DBLIB)     \
    $(LIBS)

#------------ Make ontop (Add script)---------                   
$(BIN)/ontop: ontop.o getname.o err.o
    cc -o $@         \
    ontop.o   \
    getname.o    \
    err.o      \
    $(DBLIB)     \
    $(LIBS)

#------------ Make CREQ (FPC Requests ) ---------            
$(BIN)/CREQ: $(THIRDOBJS)
    cc -o $@         \
    $(THIRDOBJS)  \
    $(DBLIB)     \
    $(LIBS)

#------------ Make xltscri (Select script)---------                   
$(BIN)/xltscri: xltscri.o getname.o err.o
    cc -o $@         \
    xltscri.o   \
    getname.o    \
    err.o    \
    $(DBLIB)         \
    $(LIBS)

#---------------End of Makefile ---------------------
```

Comment: You might have some extra \  in your file. You could consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` to debug your `Makefile`. And you probably should use `$(CC)` instead of `cc`

Comment: You have extra backslash here: `$(BIN)/xltscri \\`

Comment: actually it's before '#---------------- Common object Modules -------------        '

Comment: This is not related to C at all

Answer (score 2):

@Eugene SH. nailed it and @Ingo Leonhardt as well.  Extra backslash in the last line of the All executables section caused the program to think the next line (until the whitespace) was part of the command.  Thanks. Being new to makefiles there's no telling how much time I would have wasted before noticing that.